# css fontface doesn't work with Trajan in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

i want to use trajan pro on my website. I've .otf file of this font and sent it to fonts folder in my ftp. It doesn't work only in `internet explorer`. How can i solve the problem? By the way i tried to generate webfont kit on a website Turkish character problem occured.

Here is my css codes;

```
@font-face{ font-family: trajan_reg; src: url("../fonts/TrajanPro-Regular.otf"); }

ul.navbar-nav li a{ color: #FFF !important; font-family: trajan_reg; }
```

Comment: You need to use an .eot format of font in order to make it works o IE.

Comment: @Fags, you only need to enclose strings inside `'` if there are spaces in the family name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use an .eot format of font in order to make it works on IE. Generate a .eot version of your font from here- [the font-face generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator)

Then use it on css-

```
@font-face {font-family: 'trajan_reg';
           src: url('../fonts/TrajanPro-Regular.eot');
           src: url('../fonts/TrajanPro-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('../fonts/TrajanPro-Regular.woff') format('woff'),url('../fonts/TrajanPro-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');}

ul.navbar-nav li a{ color: #FFF !important; font-family: trajan_reg; }
```

Comment: really appreciated :))